# Invoke lambda in selector Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I need to have left join in my Linq2Entity query, so I do this and it works:

```
var query = _docDedRepository.Table
    .GroupJoin(_actQueueRepository.Table, row => row.Act.ID, actQueue => actQueue.id_act, (left, rights) => new { left, rights = rights.DefaultIfEmpty() })
    .SelectMany(row => row.rights.Select(aq => new { row.left, Status = aq == null ? ConstValues.Statuses.STATUS_NOT_IN_QUEUE : aq.status }));
```

I want to create extension method to do it more simple:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TOuter> outer, IQueryable<TInner> inner,
    Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector, 
    Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    if (outer == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("outer");
    if (inner == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("inner");
    if (outerKeySelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("outerKeySelector");
    if (innerKeySelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("innerKeySelector");
    if (resultSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("resultSelector");

    return outer
        .GroupJoin(inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, (left, rights) => Tuple.Create(left, rights.DefaultIfEmpty()))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Item2.Select(right => resultSelector(x.Item1, right)));
}
```

But I have an error from Entity Framework that query does not support an Invoke. Can I do this by Expression or smth else?

Comment: I guess `Tuple.Create(...)` should be replaced to `new { left, rights = rights.DefaultIfEmpty() }` and `resultSelector` should be Expression.

Comment: Nothing differences between anonymous object and tuple in this case. What do you mean with "resultSelector should be Expression"? If I make resultSelector type of Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>>, I can't invoke it like a delegate

Comment: Well, Entity Framework doesnt invoke `delegate`/`Func`(maybe you got `NotSupportedException` or `AggregateException`) and recognize `Tuple.Create(...)`.